# Google maps или yandex карта

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

Я только только начал изучать Андроид и хотел создать маленькое приложение каторое будет работать с онлайн картой.

У меня возник вопрос, какой выбрать и конечно попробовал оба варианта и обоих не смог устанавить (Сложно, ибо все туториалы устарели или для Эклипс).

Какой посоветуете и если не трудно дайте пожалуйста ссылку На актуальный туториал установки карты на Android Studio…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Android Studio Google Maps добавить очень просто.

Кликаете на package правой кнопкой: `New` → `Google` → `Google maps activity`.

[Тут](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm) почитать можно

Comment: @NoName Пожалуйста, отметьте, ответ как принятый, если он решил ваш вопрос (зелёная галочка слева от ответа).